# C# and WPF image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I am trying to do a simple open dialog box and add image jpeg file to image object, i am sooo close... i hope, but not sure what am i missing, any help would be appreciated, got the C# code and wpf below:

```
private void btn_Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.Filter = "Image jpeg(*.jpg)|*.jpg|Image png(*.png)|*.png";
     ofd.DefaultExt = ".jpeg";
     Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();

     Images i = new Images();

     // Process open file dialog box results 
     if (result == true)
     {
         // Open document 

         i.Imagepath = ofd.FileName;

         Cropped.Source = i;

     }  
}
```

its showing error on the Crooped.Source = i, Cropped is the image name, which i am going to take it a step further where the user with mouse control will crop the image.

below is the wpf xaml:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="291" Margin="26,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="313">
    <Image x:Name="Cropped" Source="{Binding}" />
</Border>
```

Comment: The fact that you are binding to the data context itself is likely a big source of your problem; you also aren't doing anything with the Image object you created (and `Image` is not an `ImageSource`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void btn_Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Image jpeg(*.jpg)|*.jpg|Image png(*.png)|*.png";
    ofd.DefaultExt = ".jpeg";

    // Process open file dialog box results 
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        Cropped.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofd.FileName));
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
if (result == true)
            {
                Cropped.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofd.FileName));
            }
```

Comment: because you are not explaining why it work. Every answer should come with a simple explanation about why it resolve the problem (P.S. i'm not the downvoter)

Comment: Probably because you have posted exactly the same as shown in the other answer.

Comment: BIG thanks that worked :) Both solutions worked, wish i can give both credit :(